# How we sum the value of unique record in sql

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table which contains the following columns:

```
ProductName copmanyname arianame    bno     mrp  exp_date   Date        qty 
DANZEN DS   HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J026    215 01-Feb-16   30-Oct-19   41  
DANZEN DS   HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  J026    215 01-Feb-16   30-Aug-19   2   
HIPRO       HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J035    225 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-18   20  
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   2   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   8   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    TANK    J004    135 01-Feb-16   30-May-20   1   
ALINAMIN F  HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  I002    195 02-Feb-16   30-Sep-19   2   
ALINAMIN F  HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  H003    195 02-Feb-16   30-Nov-18   1
```

I want to display the record on specific date, and which Record have same Product and company and bno and mrp then the qty of the these record wil sum. for example in above table :

```
ProductName copmanyname arianame    bno     mrp  exp_date   Date        qty
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   30
```

I tried with the following statement but it not sum up the qty, display all record.

```
SELECT  
    ProductName, CopmanyName, AriaName, bno, mrp, exp_date, 
    Sum(quantity) AS qty 
FROM
    q_saledetail
GROUP BY 
    ProductName, CopmanyName, AriaName, bno, mrp, exp_date,date 
WHERE
    date = any date
```

Comment: please correct your question: with product, Company, bno and mrp the qty should be 10, not 30 ...

Comment: Explain how you get 30 as the desired result.  I get 2 + 8 = 10.  The other 20 is for a different product.

Comment: You want to do a group by Date right? but what date you want to have in your result table? max(date)?

Comment: *"which Record have same Product and company and bno and mrp then the qty of the these record wil sum"* > Which would lead to a `qty` of 10 according to your sample, your expected output has `qty` of 30.

Comment: actually I think the total would be 2 or 8 because the arianame (area?) is different for each entry, if OP wants one line then me needs to remove the AriaName from the select query or add in    WHERE AriaName Like "CITY%"

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: There are *no* two records with matching values in all of these fields: `ProductName, CopmanyName, AriaName, bno, mrp, exp_date,date`. Just look at the `expdate` and `arianame` fields. The only two matching expdates values have different `arianame` values.

Comment: You only want that single row as result?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query in your question greatly differs from what you are asking to get as a result. Additionally your desired output seems to be off in quantity.

If you want the sum of the quantity, where Productname, companyname,bno and mrp are identical, then it is wrong to group by exp_date and date as well.

If you take a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/825fc/2/0), I have filtered by a random date and then grouped by the 4 columns you have mentioned.

```
SELECT  
    ProductName, companyName, bno, mrp, SUM(qty) as Quantity

FROM
    FiddleTable
WHERE [date] = '30-Nov-20'
GROUP BY 
    ProductName, companyName, bno, mrp
```

Comment: Thanks of all i got the idea form above suggestion and my work is done . Actually i want to display the product record which have same name, same bno and same mrp show at one place with sum of quantity. its Done very well with the help of yours instruction . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to make the other comments clear:

```
ProductName copmanyname arianame    bno     mrp  exp_date   Date        qty 
DANZEN DS   HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J026    215 01-Feb-16   30-Oct-19   41  
DANZEN DS   HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  J026    215 01-Feb-16   30-Aug-19   2  
                            ^ can you see the different arianame? ^^^ date??

HIPRO       HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J035    225 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-18   20  

NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   2   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   8   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    TANK    J004    135 01-Feb-16   30-May-20   1   
                            ^ again ^^^^

ALINAMIN F  HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  I002    195 02-Feb-16   30-Sep-19   2   
ALINAMIN F  HELIX PHARMA    CITY 2  H003    195 02-Feb-16   30-Nov-18   1 
                            ^ and   ^^^^                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

if you take a look at NOGARD: you have 3 different rows - they cant be grouped. if you spare out arianame AND bno - then you could group NOGARD to qty 10 ...

Comment: or if you wanted those from CITY and disregard TANK you can add in a WHERE clause   --- WHERE AriaName LIKE "CITY%" this will get the total of 10.

Comment: NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   2   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1  J010    135 01-Feb-16   30-Nov-20   8   
NOGARD      HELIX PHARMA    CITY 1    J004    135 01-Feb-16   30-May-20   1

Comment: still J010 and J004 mixed -> not a group. if you are using mysql, see the answer from blag -> and if this is the answer you need, accept it as answer, so anyone can see it´s done

Comment: Yes you are right. but i got a full idea with your suggestion . Thanks its very help full.

Answer (score 0):

You don't told us the DB you use (I expect MySQL);

Then you have many bug in your query, and probably in your algorithm either.

This is what I think you may look after :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2d6/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE q_saledetail
    (`ProductName` varchar(10), `copmanyname` varchar(12), `arianame` varchar(6), `bno` varchar(4), `mrp` int, `exp_date` varchar(9), `Date` varchar(9), `qty` int)
;

INSERT INTO q_saledetail
    (`ProductName`, `copmanyname`, `arianame`, `bno`, `mrp`, `exp_date`, `Date`, `qty`)
VALUES
    ('DANZEN DS', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 1', 'J026', 215, '01-Feb-16', '30-Oct-19', 41),
    ('DANZEN DS', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 2', 'J026', 215, '01-Feb-16', '30-Aug-19', 2),
    ('HIPRO', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 1', 'J035', 225, '01-Feb-16', '30-Nov-18', 20),
    ('NOGARD', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 1', 'J010', 135, '01-Feb-16', '30-Nov-20', 2),
    ('NOGARD', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 2', 'J010', 135, '01-Feb-16', '30-Nov-20', 8),
    ('NOGARD', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'TANK', 'J004', 135, '01-Feb-16', '30-May-20', 1),
    ('ALINAMIN F', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 1', 'I002', 195, '02-Feb-16', '30-Sep-19', 2),
    ('ALINAMIN F', 'HELIX PHARMA', 'CITY 2', 'H003', 195, '02-Feb-16', '30-Nov-18', 1)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT  
    ProductName, copmanyname, arianame, bno, mrp, exp_date,`Date`,
    Sum(qty) AS quantity
FROM
    q_saledetail
WHERE
    `Date` = '30-Nov-20'
GROUP BY 
    ProductName, copmanyname, arianame, bno, mrp, exp_date,`Date`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2d6/6/0)**:

```
| ProductName |  copmanyname | arianame |  bno | mrp |  exp_date |      Date | quantity |
|-------------|--------------|----------|------|-----|-----------|-----------|----------|
|      NOGARD | HELIX PHARMA |   CITY 1 | J010 | 135 | 01-Feb-16 | 30-Nov-20 |        2 |
|      NOGARD | HELIX PHARMA |   CITY 2 | J010 | 135 | 01-Feb-16 | 30-Nov-20 |        8 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
 -- or if you want to group by  `arianame` too

SELECT  
    ProductName, copmanyname, GROUP_CONCAT(arianame), bno, mrp, exp_date,`Date`,
    Sum(qty) AS quantity
FROM
    q_saledetail
WHERE
    `Date` = '30-Nov-20'
GROUP BY 
    ProductName, copmanyname, bno, mrp, exp_date,`Date`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7b2d6/6/1)**:

```
| ProductName |  copmanyname | GROUP_CONCAT(arianame) |  bno | mrp |  exp_date |      Date | quantity |
|-------------|--------------|------------------------|------|-----|-----------|-----------|----------|
|      NOGARD | HELIX PHARMA |          CITY 1,CITY 2 | J010 | 135 | 01-Feb-16 | 30-Nov-20 |       10 |
```